# Android Custom Drawable bounds

Tags: android, drawable

I'm write a custom Drawable, a text over a bitmap:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(badge, matrix, null); 
    canvas.drawText(count, size / 2, size / 2 + (text_size) / 2 , p);
}
```

When I use my drawable in an imageView, it's fine.
[image: good]

But if I use this with a textview (compound drawable) it's alignement is wrong.
[image: wrong]

I tried both setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds and setCompoundDrawables

Same results, what did I miss ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I manage to get the right alignment (my drawable is a circle/square so width == height):

In my Custom_Drawable ctor:

```
Custom_Drawable(int size) {
    this.size = size;
}
```

onDraw method:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // draw here
    setBounds(0, 0, this.size, this.size);
}
```

When setting the drawable :

```
 b.setCompoundDrawables(new Custom_Drawable(25), null, null, null);
```