# Change marker bounds for android google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

So I have a customoverlay which extend itemizedoverlay in order to place a marker on the map. My problem is that I'd like to adjust the marker so the drawable's bounds are different from the boundCenterBottm and boundCenter values (in my case I'd like to have something like boundLeftBottom if it existed). How do I achieve this? The reason I want to achieve this is because I have a drawable which points down to the left bottom corner.

I've searched the web dry, any help is greatly appreciated.

Suggesting making even transparent space to the left side will not be accepted. I consider this an improper workaround

Edit;

I ended up with this:

```
public class CustomOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> {
    private ArrayList<CustomOverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<CustomOverlayItem>();
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
//      super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        super(defaultMarker);
        defaultMarker.setBounds(0, -defaultMarker.getIntrinsicHeight(), defaultMarker.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);  //TODO experiment
        mContext = context;
    }
```

This is correct though it didn't fix my problem due to the grafic not being perfect in the corner and with 3 different drawables that would be a pain to fix (so final solution is that I'm going to fix the drawable).

Comment: Have you tried subclassing Drawable like they suggest here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855194/android-custom-drawable-bounds

Comment: You can try to override the CustomOverlay's draw method and change the bounds of the marker by adjusting its position manually. Other option would be to create a method such as boundCenter() what adjusts a drawable's bounds so that (0,0) is the center of the drawable, that's useful for "waypoint badge"-like graphics.

Comment: Both good suggestions, will try to work with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

boundCenterBottom and boundCenter are helper functions that call setBounds on the drawable... You can just call that yourself.

For bottom left, I think it will look something like this:

```
drawable.setBounds(0, -drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);
```

But that was just off the top of my head.

Comment: Will try this out and post my results.

Comment: Problem when you extend itemizedoverlay is that you have to use boundCenterBottom or boundCenter from the constructor, so this wont work, I'll try to make my own drawable.

Comment: If I just could override the constructor of itemizedoverlay it would be easy to override these methodes or make my own.

Comment: If you extend ItemizedOverlay, the constructor that you have to provide must take a Drawable as the only parameter, but you don't have to call boundCenterBottom or boundCenter on that Drawable. You can set the bounds of the Drawable before you pass it to the constructor, or make your own public Drawable boundBottomLeft(Drawable) method, which performs the setBounds on the given Drawable and returns it (it is all boundCenterBottom and boundCenter do)

Comment: Ye I figured that out myself, I'll do a final test tonight :) so far it seems like this does the charm.