# Android Google maps v2 - setOnMarkerClickListener for markers with different z-index

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

**Requirement:**

If I have 20 markers - 10 blue and 10 red in and around the same LatLng. I want the blue markers above the red, hence I added the z-index for the blue markers. I must be able to click any marker and get setOnMarkerClickListener for the specific marker I clicked irrespective of z-Index.

**Blue Markers**

```
mMapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("BluePin1").zIndex(1.0f).snippet("Address Blue1").icon(bluepins));
```

**Red Markers**

```
mMapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("RedPin1").snippet("Address Red1").icon(redpins));
```

**Question:** The markers with higher z-index(Blue marker) always takes priority even if I click the red marker. Is there a way that a marker click event doesn't take preference with respect to z-index when clicked?

NOTE : I am using Google play services version 10.0.0

Comment: Can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433983/change-marker-bounds-for-android-google-maps?rq=1)